# Position of getReviewsSummaryHtml(()

Tags: magento

I'm relatively new to Magento, so please go easy on me if the below is a stupid obvious question!!

I wish to move the output from:

```
$this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), false, true);
```

Currently it is in my main view.phtml as shown in this code section (it's five lines from the bottom):

```
    <div class="product-shop">
        <div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            <div class="coda-slider-wrapper">
                <div class="coda-slider preload" id="coda-slider-1">

                    <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
                        <div class="panel box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
                            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                                <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
                                <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
                                <?php endif;?>
                                <?php echo $html; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach;?>

                </div><!-- .coda-slider -->
            </div><!-- .coda-slider-wrapper -->
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), false, true); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
```

**With the line in this position output is correct, producing the correct "1 Review(s) | Add Your Review" on the page.**

I have include the code above the line as it is pertinent to this question. As you can see, I am utilising coda-slider, it works a treat, and produces 4 tabs. The XML relevant is:

```
            <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.tips" as="tips" template="catalog/product/view/tips.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.delivery" as="delivery" template="catalog/product/view/delivery.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="catalog/product/view/reviews.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

What I wish to do is to move the code, to be included in one of the tabs, the one created in the XML above utilising "reviews.phtml", the code for which is:

```
    <h2 class="title"><?php echo $this->__('Reviews') ?></h2>
    <?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
    if( count( $_items ) ){
        // Once we've stored the reviews, we can loop through them and get the data we need from each
        foreach( $_items as $_review ){?>
            <p><strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $_review->getTitle() );?></strong> by <?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $_review->getNickname() );?></p>
            <p class="reviewBody"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $_review->getDetail() ); ?> </p>
        <?php
        }
    }

    echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), false, true);

    ?>
```

Now here is the problem, in this position, the code throws the following error and call stack:

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on a non-object in /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php on line 67

    Call Stack:
        0.0010     632248   1. {main}() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/index.php:0
        0.0090     667600   2. Mage::run() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/index.php:81
        0.0340     887168   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/Mage.php:640
        0.6510    3469248   4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:347
        0.6610    3615704   5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176
        0.6680    3693584   6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250
        0.7280    4461864   7. Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:420
        0.7290    4477472   8. Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php:132
        1.3449   14029888   9. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php:147
        1.3449   14031072  10. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:391
        1.3449   14031152  11. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:529
        1.3449   14031952  12. Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863
        1.3449   14031952  13. Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286
        1.3470   14032496  14. Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272
        1.3479   14076336  15. include('/home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml') /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241
        1.4389   14679288  16. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml:48
        1.4389   14679384  17. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:526
        1.4389   14679384  18. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:582
        1.4389   14679616  19. Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863
        1.4389   14679792  20. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php:43
        1.4389   14680024  21. Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863
        1.4389   14680024  22. Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286
        1.4399   14680160  23. Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272
        1.4409   14722936  24. include('/home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/design/frontend/LDB_default/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml') /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241
        1.4589   14890792  25. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildGroup() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/design/frontend/LDB_default/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:57
        1.4679   14919344  26. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:785
        1.4679   14919440  27. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:526
        1.4679   14919440  28. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:582
        1.4829   15243672  29. Mage_Review_Block_Product_View->_toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863
        1.4829   15243912  30. Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php:47
        1.4829   15243912  31. Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286
        1.4829   15244056  32. Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272
        1.4839   15286864  33. include('/home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/design/frontend/LDB_default/default/template/catalog/product/view/reviews.phtml') /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241
        1.4849   15287504  34. Mage_Review_Block_Product_View->getReviewsSummaryHtml() /home/default/littledickybird.co.uk/user/htdocs/1.6/app/design/frontend/LDB_default/default/template/catalog/product/view/reviews.phtml:12
```

I am guessing that it is something to do with the fact that $this is now a "Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List" as opposed to a "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View", but I have absolutely no idea what to do about it!!!

Please help! (and yes, that is a rather desperate plea!)
Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards to all,
Andy.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for posting the error and stack trace, it makes debugging so much easier.

A quick check of the source code shows the following line isn't returning a block:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_review_list.count')
```

If you look at any `layout/review.xml` file you will see that `review_product_list` section contains a line to create that missing block.

```
<block type="core/template" name="product_review_list.count" template="review/product/view/count.phtml" />
```

You could copy that into your layout at the point where you want the count to show. If you don't want to see the count then the template isn't needed, any block with that name will do:

```
<block type="core/abstract" name="product_review_list.count" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, although not the full solution, it set me on the right path. I would vote your answer up, but I need a reputation of 15.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to clockworkgeek for his assistance, it set me on the right path to finding a solution.

His solution provided me with the "1 Review(s)", but not the "Add Your Review".

On investigation I found that "Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List" overwrites the function getReviewsSummaryHtml, as defined in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract. One difference appears to be that it doesn't call the "summary" template.

The solution was to essentially turn the XML inside out, from:

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="catalog/product/view/reviews.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
```

to:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="catalog/product/view/reviews.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews_list" as="reviewslist" template="catalog/product/view/reviewslist.phtml" />
</block>
```

Change the reviews.phtml template to:

```
<h2 class="title"><?php echo $this->__('Reviews') ?></h2>
<?php
    echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), false, true);
    echo $this->getChildhtml('reviewslist');
?>
```

and add the second template, reviewslist.phtml:

```
<?php 
    $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
    if( count( $_items ) ){
        // Once we've stored the reviews, we can loop through them and get the data we need from each
        foreach( $_items as $_review ){?>
            <p><strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $_review->getTitle() );?></strong> by <?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $_review->getNickname() );?></p>
            <p class="reviewBody"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $_review->getDetail() ); ?> </p>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

I then have access to the correct getReviewsSummaryHtml() in reviews.phtml and access to the reviews list in reviewslist.phtml

Well, it seems to work, but I would love to read anyones comments on my solution, especially if you see any glaring errors in my approach or know of a more efficient/elegant solution.

Regards,
Andy